# Is there an easy way to install OpenCV on Raspberry pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, installation

There are many steps while installing OpenCV on Raspberry pi . Is there any chance to install by using a single command. I tried `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The main one liner is with pip *The Python Package Installer* but to make it work you also need some dependencies that may or may not be installed already from other related tools.

```
$ pip3 install opencv-python
$ sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev libjasper-dev libqtgui4 python3-pyqt5 libqt4-test libilmbase-dev libopenexr-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libavcodec58 libavformat58 libswscale5
```

In addition with the current newest version you need to set an env variable to run it, `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0` [referenced issue](https://github.com/piwheels/packages/issues/59)

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0 python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

If you are really opposed to that you can use a previous version that doesn't have this issue. Don't forget to uninstall the other version if you already installed it `pip3 uninstall opencv-python`

```
$ pip3 install opencv-python==4.1.0.25
```

---

On a newly flashed `2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite` img after adding ssh access and connecting that way.

1. system update and install pip3

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

2. version check

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
$ pip3 --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

3. install openCV and check version

```
$ pip3 install opencv-python
$ pip3 freeze | grep opencv-python
opencv-python==4.1.1.26
```

4. test and fail,

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libwebp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

5. install dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev libjasper-dev libqtgui4 python3-pyqt5 libqt4-test libilmbase-dev libopenexr-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libavcodec58 libavformat58 libswscale5
```

6. test with env variable set

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0 python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using .whl files. When you want to install a package with pip, it searches for a precompiled version of that package that is compatible with your system.

In your case, pip is looking for an OpenCV Python package compatible with armv7l platform, if it cannot find a precompiled .whl file to install, it tries to download the source as .tar.gz and compile it by itself on Raspberry Pi (which is a real pain.)

armv7l compatible .whl files are available for OpenCV Python now and you can use pip to install it directly with `pip install opencv-python` command but sometimes pip tries to install the latest package and sometimes it is not armv7l compatible. I suggest you check packages and put version specifications to the command.

To handle this situation a lot easier with installations of prerequisites and preparation of the installation environment; you can use complete guides like [in this blog post for beginners](https://singleboardblog.com/install-python-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/)