# How to cross compile a rust project with opencv package for armv7

Tags: opencv, rust, cross-compiling, apt

I have a simple rust application which compiles without errors on my Ubuntu host machine.
The Cargo.toml looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "openvc-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
opencv = "0.66"
```

Then I tried to cross compile this project for armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, so that I can run the binary on a raspberry. I used the [cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross) tool for this purpose. The [FAQ](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross/wiki/FAQ#external-dependencies) of the cross project has some information about how to handle external libraries. So I tried to install `libopencv-dev:armhf` on the docker image just like in the examples of the FAQ. However, I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv-dev:armhf : Depends: libopencv3.2-java:armhf (= 3.2.0+dfsg-6) but it is not installable
                       Recommends: opencv-data:armhf but it is not installable
```

I also tried to use Debian repositories as described in the FAQ. The error is the same.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue? Or is there another way of cross compiling a rust project that I can try?

Compiling on the raspberry does not work, compilation gets stuck at package opencv. I think it is due to the limited performance of the rapsberry?

Comment: sounds like raspberry is not easy. check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60102838/175554 may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing a precompiled opencv package in the docker container does not work (still don't know why), but cross compiling the correct opencv version does work. See the following docker file:

```
ARG CROSS_BASE_IMAGE
FROM $CROSS_BASE_IMAGE

# requirements of bindgen, see https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/requirements.html
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y llvm-dev libclang-dev clang 

# cross compile opencv, see https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d76/tutorial_arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf git build-essential cmake
RUN git clone --depth 1 --branch '4.5.1' https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git && \
    cd opencv/platforms/linux && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../../.. && \
    make && \
    make install

ENV CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opencv/platforms/linux/build/install"
```

In `Cross.toml` you simply specify the path of the dockerfile, e.g.:

```
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
dockerfile = "./Dockerfile"
```

Cross compiling the Rust project:

```
cross build --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

The initial setup of the docker container takes quite a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the crate's github page had a working docker image for it:
https://github.com/twistedfall/opencv-rust/blob/master/INSTALL.md#crosscompilation

I haven't gotten it to work through `cross`, but it works just fine if you mount your repository in that image and build with `cargo-xbuild`:

```bash
# follow instructions in repo to get rpi-xcompile image
docker run --rm -v .:/src -it rpi-xcompile /bin/bash
cd /src
cargo-xbuild
```

Comment: Could you give a more detailed explanation of what you did? I'm new to Docker so I'm not sure what "mount your repository in that image" really entails.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to make every SO docker answer be a docker tutorial. But - to answer your question, mounting the repository means to use the volume mount option -v to make the place you cloned your rust project accessible in the container. -v .:/src means mount the current directory at /src in the container. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ for docs on all the options. I've also updated the GitHub link as it had been moved. I'd like to avoid pasting a large amount of potentially out of date instructions from that link here.